# Run .sh file instead of opening it

Tags: shell-script, files, gui

I am using Zorin OS 7. I want to run a `.sh` file but I can't seem to be able to—it just opens in a text editor.

Also under RMB>open with there is no other option.

Comment: If your GUI is failing you, there's always the option of running your script in a terminal. Open a terminal window, use `cd` to change to the folder where your script is located, and execute it as `./myscript.sh`.

Comment: I did the cd not sure how to enter the filename though. what would i do if the filename is called pycharm.sh

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In a terminal type this to execute a script:

```
$ ./pycharm.sh
```

You might need to make it executable too:

```
$ chmod +x pycharm.sh
```

Comment: $: command not found

Comment: You're not supposed to type the `$` ;)

Comment: @user320 - I almost said that in my answer but didn't want to offend you, i always include dollar signs to show a prompt when I give examples 8-). Thanks Martin!

Comment: Its all good. No offense here. Thanks for your guys help.